# Removing a Table From CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-model

I am trying to remove a table from CakePHP. All the tables were created with the cake bake function and I have removed the table from all the models. But when I remove the table from the database I get an error message:

```
Error: Database table channels_offers for model ChannelsOffer was not found.

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app/views/errors/missing_table.ctp
```

So how do I remove a table that was originally baked in?

Answer (score 3):

Well, it appears that you still have a model called `ChannelsOffer`.  You would need to add a property to your `ChannelsOffer` model.  Here's an example

```
class ChannelsOffer extends AppModel {

    // this tells the model not to use a table, alternatively you could supply your 
    // own table name here.
    public $useTable = false;
```